# Query 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if someone can help me with my query.

This is my query that works great:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT primary_key, address, postcode, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5"
```

I also need to retrieve data from a table called products; the primary key, col1 and col2.
The primary key being the common field.

How would I add to this query?
Hope someone can help me?

Many thanks

---

**Repsonse to rap-2-h's Answer**
Thank you to everyone who responded.

Thanks for the code rap-2-h this worked great and retrieved all the stores and the products.

Can you help me further please?
The original code that I gave shows the 3 closest stores to the location the user types in. I also want to list, with each store, the range of products that store holds.

The code you gave me works, but the store name and address is duplicated the amount of products it stores.

For example:

Store 1,
Address,
Product 1

Store 1,
Address,
Product 2

Store 1,
Address,
Product 3

**Rather than:**
Store 1,
Address,
Product 1,
Product 2,
Product 3

Hope you can guide me in the right direction on this. 
Many thanks for your help.

Would I have to create another table as mentioned by Markus Hofmann?

The structure of the database is basically the stores table that contains the store id, name and address and the products database contains all the products with the store id.

Store 1 can have product 1, product 2 and product 4.

Store 2 can have product 1, product 2 and product 3.

Store 3 can have product 2, product 3 and product 4.

Thanks again

Comment: You have to do a join. An inner join would exclude stores that don't have the product: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Do you mean a `one-to-many` relationship? So a product has many stores, which means a product is available in many stores? To join the **products** table with the **stores** you need a `pivot` table called `product_store` (the table names to join, in alphabetical order). Tell me if this is what you want and I'll provide you an answer.

Comment: Do you want records that only appear in both tables, or all records from your initial query and then any matching results from the second table? You could either use an INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN depending.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! I tried inner join and it retrieved all the stores and products. I have added a response to my question above. I'm not sure if I will have to change the structure of the database. The database was given to me so I tried working with it as it is. Any ideas? Thanks again I really appreciate you guys responding.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer if you have one (e.g. a simple php loop acting on a well-formed array)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this  (an `INNER JOIN` clause as @TheGunner said):

```
SELECT stores.primary_key, products.primary_key, address, postcode, lat, lng, col1, col2, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores 
INNER JOIN products ON products.primary_key = stores.primary_key
HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5
```

(I hope I understood your question)

Comment: Thanks for this rap-@-h, this worked great and retrieved all the stores and the products. I was wondering if you could help me further? I have posted a response to your answer in my question above so it's easier to read. Hope to hear from you soon! Many thanks again for you help.

Comment: You can use this query, and doing a php loop for each row. Do you want only SQL ou PHP and SQL ?

Comment: I'm using PHP and MySQL. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Here is a quick and dirty example with PHP and MySQL : http://pastebin.com/AnqPVtdb (not sure it's what's you want, but it can help me to understand)

Comment: Hi @rap-2-h. Many thanks for the code. I followed the [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) tutorial. The closest stores are outputted into an XML format. Would the join work this way with the XML format? Thanks again.